# rails check_box_tag disapear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I want to make a form based on check_boxes, and I want it to be checked, if '@clans' array is not nil and it contains a 'value' of a given checkbox.

My first atemnpt was:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'clans[]','Feniks', true if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Feniks' %>
```

but when @clans is nil, the check_box disappears, just like it was disabled.

I managed to solve it with code like that:

```
  <% if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Feniks' %>
    Feniks: <%= check_box_tag 'clans[]','Feniks', true %>
  <% else %>
    Feniks: <%= check_box_tag 'clans[]','Feniks' %>
  <% end %>
```

but it looks so bad, that there have to be a better way to write this :)

Please show me how to handle this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `if` logic inside parenthesis.

```
<%= check_box_tag 'clans[]','Feniks', (true if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Feniks') %>
```

In your code, `if` working as a modifier. Like `print 10 if x.present?`. In this sample, if `x` is not *blank*, the this method call `print(10)` will be happened, otherwise not. Same analogy holds for your case also. Inside the *erb* tag, you code is being interpreted as :

```
<%= check_box_tag('clans[]','Feniks', true) if <condition> %>
```

That's why when *condition* is true, `check_box_tag` method is getting invoked otherwise not. You could write the whole `if` part as :

```
<%= check_box_tag 'clans[]','Feniks', @clans.try(:include?, 'Feniks') %>
```

Comment: I could swear I tried this :) I will accept when I can